# Proof for inequality containing a summatory and a product

Tags: inequality

Given the following inequality:

$$\sqrt[N]{\prod_i^N x_i} < \frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N x_i$$

for $x_i \in \mathbb{R^+_0}$ (positive reals) and $N \in \mathbb{N}^+$ (positive integer).

How can I prove that it is valid for the above conditions?

---

BTW: what is the english word for the $\prod$ operation? It has a name in spanish ([*multiplicatoria* or *productoria*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productorio)) but I have not been able to find a name for it in english other than "product".

Comment: Product is the commonly used term for $\prod$.

Comment: Yea, this is AM-GM proof, see thread that @Ravi gives.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that this was a known mathematical problem. And thank you for clarifying the name of $\prod$. I just assumed that there would be a unique name for the operation. And yes, this is indeed a duplicate of that question.

Comment: if $\{x_i\}$ are all equal then the two means are equal. You must change the $<$ symbol with the $\leq$ symbol